# Generating a UIView with an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following method that for some reason does NOT display the image:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    float cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width/RADIUS_RATIO;
    UIBezierPath *roundedRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:cornerRadius];
    [roundedRect addClip];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [roundedRect stroke];

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds,
                                   self.bounds.size.width * 0.5,
                                   self.bounds.size.height * 0.5);
    if (self.faceUp)
    {
        UIImage *cardFace = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                 @"%@%@.png",[self rankAsStrings],self.suit]];
        if (cardFace)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@%@.png",[self rankAsStrings],self.suit);
            [cardFace drawInRect:imageRect];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"No Image Found: %@%@.png",[self rankAsStrings],self.suit);
        }

    } else {
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"] drawInRect:imageRect];
    }
}
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

P.S. The images are present and I do get the "NSLog(@"%@%@.png",[self rankAsStrings],self.suit);" message in the console.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `imageRect` has 0.0 width and 0.0 height. Check the docs for `CGRectInset` method - it reduces original rect by 2*dx and 2*dy.

Comment: Thanks a bunch... Forest for the trees situation here!

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it like this :

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"MyProfilePic.png"]];
```